# Сортировка по двум колонкам в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, table

Подскажите как можно реализовать такую сортировку.
Нет ни каких идей..
"Результаты в уже созданной HTML таблице отсортировать в порядке
убывания звездности, для одинаковых звезд упорядочивание производить по
названию отеля по возрастанию".
Пока есть сортировка только по одному полю.

Вот мой код gsp странички Grails.

```js
var table = $('#mytable');
var tbody = $('#table1');

function sort_rait() {


  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    if ($('#rait_order').val() == 'desc') {
      return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());

    } else {
      return $('td:first', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first', a).text());

    }
  }).appendTo(tbody);

  var sort_order = $('#rait_order').val();

  if (sort_order == "asc") {
    document.getElementById("rait_order").value = "desc";
  }
}


window.addEventListener('load', sort_rait)
```

```css
.title {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: .3em .5em;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: seashell;
}

button {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #aac078;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
thead {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #aac078;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

thead {
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div id="header">
    <form action="/test/">
      <button type="submit">Новый поиск</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <g:set var="haveQuery" value="${params.q?.trim()}" />
  <g:set var="haveResults" value="${searchResult?.results}" />
  <g:if test="${haveResults}">
    <div class="list">
      <table id="mytable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Звёздность</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Название</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Страна</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table1">
          <g:set var="totalPages" value="${Math.ceil(searchResult.total / searchResult.max)}" />
          <g:each in="${searchResult.results}" status="i" var="htls">
            <g:if test="${htls.site}">
              <tr>
                <td>${htls.rating}</td>
                <td>${htls.name}<br><a href="${htls.site}" target="_blank" style="font-size: small">Перейти на сайт</a></td>
                <td>${htls.country}</td>
              </tr>
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
              <tr>
                <td>${htls.rating}</td>
                <td>${htls.name}</td>
                <td>${htls.country}</td>
              </tr>
            </g:else>
          </g:each>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="paginateButtons">
      <g:paginate params="[q: params.q]" total="${searchResult.total}" />
    </div>
  </g:if>
  <br/>
  <div class="title">
    <span>
        <g:if test="${haveQuery && haveResults}">
            Количество найденных отелей: <strong>${searchResult.total}</strong>
        </g:if>
        <g:else>
            <p style="text-align: center"> Пустой запрос </p>
        </g:else>
        <g:if test="${haveQuery && !haveResults && !parseException}">
            <p style="text-align: center"> По Вашему запросу ничего не найдено </p>
        </g:if>
    </span>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: добавила весь код

Answer (score 0):

По второму полю можно сортировать так же как и по первому, только с равнивать не `a` c `b`, а `b` c `a`

```js
var table = $('#mytable');
var tbody = $('#table1');

function sortRait() {
  var sortOrder = $('#rait_order').val();
  $("#rait_order").val(sortOrder == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc");
  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    var tdA = $(a).find('td');
    var tdB = $(b).find('td');
    if (sortOrder == 'desc') {
      return tdA.eq(0).text().localeCompare(tdB.eq(0).text()) ||
        tdB.eq(1).text().localeCompare(tdA.eq(1).text());
    } else {
      return tdB.eq(0).text().localeCompare(tdA.eq(0).text()) ||
        tdA.eq(1).text().localeCompare(tdB.eq(1).text());

    }
  }).appendTo(tbody);
}

$('.sorting').on('click', sortRait);

$(window).on('load', sortRait);
```

```css
.title {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: .3em .5em;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: seashell;
}

button {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #aac078;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
thead {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #aac078;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

thead {
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div id="header">
    <form action="/test/">
      <button type="submit">Новый поиск</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <table id="mytable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Звёздность</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Название</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Страна</strong></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table1">
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Отель3</td>
          <td>Страна3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Отель2</td>
          <td>Страна2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Отель1</td>
          <td>Страна1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Отель3</td>
          <td>Страна3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Отель2</td>
          <td>Страна2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Отель1</td>
          <td>Страна1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="sorting">Сортировать</button>
<input id="rait_order" type="hidden" value="asc" />
```